# Large deviations and family of probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am learning the theory of large deviations. In so many results in the theory and from the very beginning in each book about this subject one starts by introducing a family of probability measures satisfying some properties and defined on some (Polish) space. I do not understand why one needs in some important context and any context of the theory of large deviations to introduce a sequence or family of probability measures. Can somebody explain and provide some example of why one needs many, i.e. a sequence, measures ? Many thanks.

Comment: For example, it tells you about how the distribution of the sample mean behaves, on an exponential scale.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that. There is a sequence of probability measures. Why a single probability measure is not enough ? Can you provide some example ?

Comment: The sequence of measures being the law of the sample mean

Comment: This is not clear. It will be great if you post an answer and present all the details. In the case of the law of large numbers or the centrak limit theorem, one uses a single probability measure which is also be seen as the law of the sample mean.

Comment: There is a sequence of probability measures in the law of large numbers and central limit theorem as well. After all, they are theorems about weak convergence

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X<x),$ I assume that by a sequence you mean the following, $F_n(x) = \mathbb{P}_n(X_n<x).$  Why can one not interpret this as a single measure acting on a sequence of random variables, i.e. $F_n(x) = \mathbb{P}(X_n<x)$ ? As far as I can understand text books, the latter is what is meant when considering the LLN and CLT. Why it is needed to introduce  a new probability measure for each $n$ ?

Comment: In any probability book, the presentation is usually like this. Define weak convergence: $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$ if $\int fd\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for all continuous bounded $f$. Proceed to discuss intermediary material, then prove weak law of large numbers and central limit theorem. Namely, letting $\mu_n$ be the law of the sample mean, show $\mu_n\Rightarrow \delta_{E[X]}$. Surely you do not object to this presentation? The presentation in large deviations is the same. First define what a LDP is, then prove a basic one like Cramer’s theorem.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The presentation in books is similar to what one would find in wikipedia concerning for example the CLT. In Durret just like in wikipedia one uses a single measure, something like $F_n (y) = \mathbb{P} (S n / n ≤ y) \rightarrow \cdots.$ I guess your notation is more advanced. I do not know. Somehow I am not comfortable with your notation even though it is precisely this notation that is used in books about large deviations. This was my question in the post here.